# Como criar vetores de strings em java?

Tags: java, string, array

> "Faça um algoritmo para receber um inteiro n (número de alunos), um inteiro m (número de disciplinas), e nxm notas de 0 a 10, que cada aluno obteve em cada disciplina. Apresentar:
>
> a) qual (ou quais) disciplina(s) os alunos obtiveram maior nota média
>   b) qual (ou quais) disciplina(s) os alunos obtiveram menor nota média
>   c) qual (ou quais) aluno(s) obteve maior média geral
>   d) qual (ou quais) aluno(s) obteve menor média geral"

Pensei em criar uma string para os nomes dos alunos, outra para as disciplinas e então criar a matriz com as notas. Só depois eu pensaria em um jeito de calcular a média. Pelo que entendi, devo imprimir na tela os nomes das disciplinas que correspondem às maiores e menores médias; o mesmo vale para os alunos. Mas não estou conseguindo criar as tais strings...

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);
        ent.useLocale(Locale.US);
        int n, m, i, j;;
        n = ent.nextInt(); // numero de alunos
        m = ent.nextInt(); // numero de disciplinas            
        String [] a = new String[n]; // nomes dos alunos
        String [] d = new String[m]; // nomes das disciplinas
        double [][] M = new double[n][m]; // notas
        // nomes dos alunos
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            a[i] = ent.nextLine();
        }
        // nomes das disciplinas
        for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
            d[i] = ent.nextLine();
        }
        // monta tabela de notas: alunos X disciplinas
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
                M[i][j] = ent.nextDouble();
            }            
        }
        // calcula a nota média de cada disciplina
        double soma=0, media=0;
        for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
            for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
                soma = soma + M[i][j];
            }
            media = soma/n;
            System.out.println("Média de "+d[j]+": "+media);
        }
    }
```

Quando executo o programa e digito o nome do 1º aluno ou digito todos e depois dou enter, aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException   at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)     at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)  at
>   aula11.teste.main(teste.java:8) Java Result: 1

Não sei o que quer dizer nem o que devo fazer para corrigir o erro.

Comment: Porque o `ent.useLocale(Locale.US);`?

Comment: Porque uso ponto para separar decimais. Se usar vírgula dá erro.

Comment: Ainda não sei qual é o problema com o `Scanner`, mas no cálculo da média você vai precisar colocar `soma = 0;` no começo do `for` que itera o `j` no final, mas antes do `for`interno.

Comment: Ou então mover a declaração do `soma` e do `media` para o início do `for` que está logo abaixo.

Comment: Qual é a linha 8 no seu programa? É a que lê o `n`?

Comment: OK, vou providenciar isso, valeu pela dica. Por enquanto meu problema é criar as strings, senão não tenho como exibir os nomes dos alunos e das disciplinas de maior e menor médias.

Comment: Sim, a linha 8 lê n.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19046/discussion-between-cristiane-dos-santos-costa-and-victor).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Primeiramente, observe esta parte:

```java
    for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
        d[i] = ent.nextLine();
    }
```

Você itera a variável `j`, mas acessa o array usando `i`. Isso está errado. Para evitar erros como este, é recomendável declarar a variável no próprio `for`, assim:

```
    for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
        d[j] = ent.nextLine();
    }
```

E então, você não precisa mais declarar `i` e `j` fora do laço. Isso tem a vantagem que se você usar a variável errada, é mais provável que o compilador encontre o erro para você.

Prosseguindo de volta ao seu problema original, esta é a sua linha 8:

```java
n = ent.nextInt(); // numero de alunos
```

Ou seja, tem certeza que você realmente digitou um número inteiro, e não um número decimal ou o nome de algum aluno ou disciplina?

Para evitar estes tipos de problemas, recomendo colocar isso no programa, fora do método `main`, pode ser antes ou depois:

```
private static int lerInt(String mensagem, Scanner scanner) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(mensagem);
        String lido = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(lido);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Desculpe, mas " + lido + " não é um número inteiro. Tente novamente.");
        }
    }
}

private static double lerDouble(String mensagem, Scanner scanner) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(mensagem);
        String lido = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        try {
            return Double.parseDouble(lido);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Desculpe, mas " + lido + " não é um número real. Tente novamente.");
        }
    }
}

private static String lerString(String mensagem, Scanner scanner) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(mensagem);
        String lido = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        if (!lido.isEmpty()) return lido;
        System.out.println("Desculpe, você não digitou nada. Tente novamente.");
    }
}
```

E então você os utiliza desta forma:

```java
int n = lerInt("Digite o numero de alunos", ent);
int m = lerInt("Digite o numero de disciplinas", ent);

...

// nomes dos alunos
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    a[i] = lerString("Digite o nome do " + (i + 1) + "o aluno.", ent);
}
// nomes das disciplinas
for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
    d[j] = lerString("Digite o nome da " + (j + 1) + "a disciplina.", ent);
}

...

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
        M[i][j] = lerDouble("Digite a nota de " + d[j] + " do aluno " + a[i] + ".", ent);
    }
}
```

E você pode apagar estas linhas:

```java
    ent.useLocale(Locale.US);
    int n, m, i, j;;
```

Também há um probleminha no seu cálculo da média. Ao invés disso:

```java
    double soma=0, media=0;
    for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
```

Use isso:

```java
    for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
        double soma=0, media;
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
```

O motivo é que a soma tem que voltar para zero quando você muda de disciplina.

Comment: Caramba, eu errei muita coisa boba! Passo tanto tempo tentando resolver um problema que quando passo pro problema seguinte faço tudo errado. Obrigada pela ajuda!

Comment: Consegui fazer tudo funcionar direitinho! Ficou diferente do que você sugeriu (fiz de um jeito menos prático), mas suas dicas ajudaram MUITO. Obrigada mesmo!!