# Entrada específica de informação

Tags: java

O objetivo é fazer com que o programa aceite somente números no método `numero()` (não pode aceitar se for letra, ponto, interrogação, etc).

Já no método `usuario()`, somente letras (não pode aceitar números, ponto, interrogação, etc).

```
 public void numero() {
        System.out.println("Digite o número da conta: ");
        this.setNumeroConta(sc.nextInt());
        sc.nextLine();
        if (this.getNumeroConta() >= 0) {
            System.out.println("SUCESSO_NA_OPERÇÃO NUMERO_DA_CONTA");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Somente números");
    }
}

 public void usuario() {
        System.out.println("Digite o nome de usuário: ");
        this.setDono(sc.nextLine());
        if (this.getDono() != null) {
            System.out.println("SUCESSO_NA_OPERÇÃO NOME_DO_USUARIO");
        }
    } else{
        System.out.println("Somente letras");
    }

}
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta questão e na resposta dela: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42351/132

Comment: Não entendi, o enunciado me pareceu muito confuso. Teria como por exemplos do que deve ser aceitado/recusado por esses métodos? E como você os chama no programa principal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vai depender muito de onde esta vindo a informacao , se vier de uma tela (java web) voce pode usar atributo do html5 chamado pattern com o regex que pegue apenas letras pattern="[a-zA-Z]+/g" e assim  para apenas numeros pattern="[0-9]+/g", ou se vier do banco de dados voce pode usar um coalesce formatando do jeito que voce quer.

neste seu metodo voce pode colocar um construtor para garantir que ele receba so o tipo esperado e pode remover caracteres como no exemplo que fiz tambem com regex.

```js
 public void usuario(String entrada.matches("^[a-zA-Z\s]+$")) {
            System.out.println("Digite o nome de usuário: ");
        this.setDono(sc.nextLine());
        if (this.getDono() != null) {
            System.out.println("SUCESSO_NA_OPERÇÃO NOME_DO_USUARIO");
        }
    } else{
        System.out.println("Somente letras");
    }

}
```