# Por que o Scanner retorna erro em algo que está dentro do esperado?

Tags: java, scanner

Note que eu digitei, um número, um texto e um número, conforme pede aí.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int valor1 = entrada.nextInt();
        String texto = entrada.nextLine();
        int valor2 = entrada.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Veja [o erro no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WOiiYy).

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
>   at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
>   at Ideone.main(Main.java:6)
> ```

Não gostei [dessa solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42356/101). Queria saber porque dá erro, o que fazer para resolver, e se não tiver jeito se a solução do Victor Stafusa é a melhor disponível.

Comment: Algo me diz que é duplicata, mas não achei.

Comment: Concordo. Já respondi isso umas três vezes.

Comment: Mas não vou fechar como duplicata porque neste daqui, isso é o cerne do problema, e não algo tangencial, permitindo então uma resposta canônica.

Comment: Eu ia fechar ;)

Comment: Só pra explicar de outra maneira, next, nextInt, nextLong, e outros procura por um "TOKEN" especifico (independente da quantidade de caracteres), já o nextLine é que procura por linha (no caso a linha inteira até a quebra é o token para nextLine), por isto ocorre o "problema".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Vamos supor que a sua entrada é a seguinte:

```
5
Maniero
12
```

Observe que o `nextInt()` vai consumir o 5 e retornar, sem consumir a quebra-de-linha que se segue. Quando o `nextLine()` for executado, ele vai ver a quebra-de-linha, consumi-la e te dar uma string em branco.

O problema é que o `nextInt()` não consome a quebra-de-linha que se segue. Para fazê-lo consumir, a solução é ler a linha inteira (`nextLine()`) e usar o `Integer.parseInt(String)` para retirar o número de lá.

Há um detalhe importante na interpretação disso: O que você quer na verdade é **uma linha contendo um número**, um texto e **outra linha contendo um número**. E se você está lendo linhas, use `nextLine()`.

Além [da minha resposta que você linkou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42356/132), também já abordei esse problema [nesta outra resposta minha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237085/132), [nesta outra também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/261321/132) e também [nesta daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153230/132).

E por que ele não consome a quebra-de-linha? Porque você pode querer fazer isso, que vai funcionar:

Entrada:

```
1 2 3
```

Programa:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int valor1 = entrada.nextInt();
        int valor2 = entrada.nextInt();
        int valor3 = entrada.nextInt();
    }
}
```

A ideia é que o `Scanner` não deve consumir mais entrada do que é necessário para fazer o que lhe foi solicitado. Isso significa que o `nextInt()` não vai consumir a quebra-de-linha que se seguir (ou qualquer outra coisa que se seguir) porque isso seria consumir mais do que o necessário na entrada.

Comment: Corroborando com isso: https://ideone.com/Md7fKv ; depois de cada leitura mandei imprimir o que havia sido lido, o texto resgatado foi "", não "abc"

Comment: Muito bom, já tivesse esse problema e corrigi de como sugerido no meu projeto: https://github.com/giuliana-bezerra/projeto-algoritmos. Uso um menu que lê inteiros e linhas, e por isso precisei executar nextInt seguido de nextLine.

Answer (score 5):

A classe `Scanner` possui vários métodos com o termo `next*`, como sendo:

- `next()` busca e retorna o próximo TOKEN completo (retorna: `String`)
- `nextBigDecimal()` Escaneia o próximo TOKEN de um input e retorna como `BigDecimal`
- `nextBigInteger()` Escaneia o próximo TOKEN de um input e retorna como `BigInteger`
- `nextBoolean()` Analisa o próximo TOKEN de um input em retorna em um valor `boolean`
- `nextByte()` Escaneia o próximo TOKEN de um input e retorna como `byte`
- `nextDouble()` Escaneia o próximo TOKEN de um input e retorna como `double`
- `nextFloat()` Escaneia o próximo TOKEN de um input e retorna como `float`
- `nextInt()` Escaneia o próximo TOKEN de um input e retorna como `int`
- `nextLong()` Escaneia o próximo TOKEN de um input e retorna como `long`
- `nextShort()` Escaneia o próximo TOKEN de um input e retorna como `short`
- `nextLine()` Avança esse scanner além da linha atual e retorna a entrada que foi que foi "pulada" (retorna: `String`)

Esquecendo o `nextLine()`, note que todas falam de um tal de TOKEN, "mas o que é o TOKEN?", TOKEN ali se refere a algo que é esperado, no exemplo `nextInt` espera algo que foi digitado que "case" com o `int`, então se você fizer isto:

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
int valor1 = entrada.nextInt();
int valor2 = entrada.nextInt();
int valor3 = entrada.nextInt();

System.out.println("Retornou:" + valor1);
System.out.println("Retornou:" + valor2);
System.out.println("Retornou:" + valor3);
```

Mas ao invés de apertar <kbd>Enter</kbd> você digitar:

> ```
> 1    2       3
> ```

E então só depois apertar o <kbd>Enter</kbd>, note que ele irá já exibir os 3 `System.out.println`, isto porque tanto espaço quanto quebra de linha serão considerados para separar os valores, e estes valores entre as separações são os TOKENS, seja lá qual for o valor.

Agora mude para isto:

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
String valor1 = entrada.next();
String valor2 = entrada.next();
String valor3 = entrada.next();

System.out.println("Retornou:" + valor1);
System.out.println("Retornou:" + valor2);
System.out.println("Retornou:" + valor3);
```

E digite isto tudo antes de apertar o <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

> ```
> 1    2      ab
> ```

Após apertar o Enter, novamente será exibido todos os 3 `System.out.println`, então token em todos trabalham por espaços tanto quanto quebra de linhas.

### Agora o `nextLine`

A minha tradução ficou um pouco ruim, o texto original da documentação é este:

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.

Eu acho que esse texto é o que confunde muita gente, ao traduzir skipped a primeira vez eu mesmo fiquei sem entender o ignorada, não é que a linha foi "ignorada", o sentido de skipped ali é que passou para a proxima linha quando executou o método, ou seja seria mais para algo como "retorna a entrada que foi da linha que foi pulada" (não sei se pulada soa bem, talvez eu revise o texto).

Então na verdade o único que trabalha com a linha inteira ao invés dos TOKENs é o `nextLine`, ou seja é como se a linha inteira fosse um token, para explicar melhor usarei o seu próprio código (leia os comentários).

Procura o TOKEN (não precisa casar com `int`, pode ser qualquer coisa que não seja um espaço), mas se mantem na **"linha 1"**:

```
int valor1 = entrada.nextInt();
```

Ainda estamos na **"linha 1"**, mas toda função `next*` sempre vai trabalhar após o último TOKEN, então o `1` você ignora, só sobra o `\n` ou `\r\n` do input digitado, então no caso vai retornar uma `String` vazia, já que quebras de linha não são valores para os TOKENs e vai passar para a **"linha 2"**:

```
String texto = entrada.nextLine();
```

Agora estamos na **"linha 2"** e não na **"linha 3"**, mas na sua **"linha 2"** você havia digitado `abc`, o que não "casa" com o próximo comando:

```
int valor2 = entrada.nextInt();
```

Então ocorre o a exception `InputMismatchException`, seguindo o input completo

> 123
>   abc
>   456

Answer (score 2):

> Queria saber porque dá erro

O programa dá erro porque a primeira chamada a `entrada.nextInt()` nao muda de linha. de forma a que quando voce chama `entrada.nextLine()` o scanner mudará de linha e retornará uma string vazia. Ou seja até este ponto tem que:

```
valor1 = 123 
texto = ""
```

De forma a que quando voce faz a segunda chamada a `entrada.nextInt()`, como nao há mais nenhum inteiro na linha, ocorre uma excepção.

> O que fazer para resolver

A resolução depende do funcionamento do seu programa, bem como, estabelecer rigorosamente como o utilizador deve introduzir os dados na sua aplicação. Neste caso vou assumir que voce quer manter o seu input conforme ele está.

**Tratar o input do utilizador**

De forma geral, você deve fazer seu código de forma a que se o utilizador introduzir os dados num formato não esperado, ele possa ter informação sobre o problema e possa retificá-lo..

Tenha atenção que no seu código podem ocorrer diversos outros problemas relacionados a este motivo. Logo na primeira chamada a `entrada.nextInt()` o programa poderá dar um erro caso o utilizador introduza caracteres que não sejam dígitos.

**Tratar o problema de forma imediata**

Se estiver á procura da solução imediata, sempre que voce fizer uma chamada a `nextXXX` que nao seja `nextLine()` voce deverá também chamar `nextLine()` consequentemente. Ou seja, ler um número deverá ser feito da seguinte forma.

```
 int valor1 = entrada.nextInt();  
 entrada.nextLine();
```

**Tratar o problema com o devido cuidado**

Eventualmente poderá ser interessante fazer um método com este código e que que eventualmente trate também o input do utilizador. Algo parecido a isto

```
private static Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
public static int readInt(String name){
    System.out.println("Introduza " + name);
    while(true){
        try{
            int valor = entrada.nextInt();
            return valor;
        }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.print(name + " deve ser um inteiro. Tente novamente.");
        }finally{
            entrada.nextLine();
        }
    }    
}
```

Esta código pode ter imensos defeitos, mas com certeza, pelo menos demonstra uma maior tolerância a input inválidos por parte do utilizador.