# Programa que lê número real em Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Estou com uma dúvida bastante idiota digamos assim, mas não estou lembrando o que devo fazer para ficar correto. Devo criar um programa que leia um número inteiro e imprima na tela.

Eis o que tenho:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Real {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        double real;

        Scanner le = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Digite um numero real");
        real = le.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("O numero digitado é:" +real);

        le.close();


    }

}
```

Eu consigo digitar o número (digitei por exemplo 2.35) porém da o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Digite um numero real
> 3.2
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
>     at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
>     at Real.main(Real.java:14)
> ```

Me ajudem. Não devo usar `if`, `else`, nada. É um exercício básico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar `nextLine()` e depois `Double.parseDouble`. O motivo de fazer isso é o que é explanando [nessa outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262976/132).

Seu código fica assim:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Real {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner le = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite um número real");
        double real = Double.parseDouble(le.nextLine());
        System.out.println("O número digitado é: " + real);
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/HBw1Nr)

Entretanto, no seu enunciado, você fala de números inteiros, e não números reais. Nesse caso, você usaria `int`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Inteiro {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner le = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Digite um número inteiro");
        int inteiro = Integer.parseInt(le.nextLine());
        System.out.println("O número digitado é: " + inteiro);
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/K0TA2O)

Comment: tenho que usar Parse?
pois para esse exercicio(na epoca que aprendi não vi isso..alias só vi isso semana passada)

Comment: @CarolM Não, não tem que fazer isso. Mas isso é para evitar usar o `nextDouble` e o `nextInt` que vão te causar problemas, tais como expliquei na [minha resposta da outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/262981/132). Não vale a pena ficar quebrando cabeça com uma coisa dessas, ainda mais quando se é iniciante.

Comment: Desculpa a chatice e a ignorancia,mas se eu tiver que usar apenas o nextDouble,o que devo arrumar no meu código?

Comment: @CarolM Testei o seu código e... Ele funcionou! Veja aqui: https://ideone.com/zoYgXu

Comment: nossa eu rodo no java e ele da o erro que citei!

Comment: Achei o erro Victor!

Eu estava digitando : 2.35 e não 2,35