# Problema com código em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Pessoal estou fazendo um programa em Java básico. No momento tem 6 classes, porém, está tendo problema em 2 classes na hora do cadastro. Estou fazendo um SET para cadastrar o nome do jogador na lista encadeada e depois no case 6 estou tentando imprimir pra ver se realmente está funcionando. (Mas não imprime nada)

Lista encadeada:

```
public class ListaEncadeada {

  private Nodo inicio;
  private Nodo fim;
  private int quantos;
  private int capacidade;

  public ListaEncadeada(int capacidade) {
    this.capacidade = capacidade;
  }

  public ListaEncadeada() {
    this.capacidade = 100;
  }

  public int getCapacidade() {
    return capacidade;
  }

  public int incluirJogador(Jogador umJogador) {

    Nodo temp = new Nodo();
    temp.setInfo(umJogador);
    if (quantos == 0) {
      inicio = fim = temp;
    } else if (quantos <= capacidade) {
      fim.setProx(temp);
      fim = temp;
    }
    quantos++;
    return 2;
  }

  public int getTamanho() {
    return quantos;
  }

  public Jogador get(int indice) {
    if ((indice >= 0) && (indice < quantos)) {
      Nodo temp = inicio;
      for (int i = 0; i < indice; i++) {
        temp = temp.getProx();
      }
      return temp.getInfo();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

e a da interface está assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Menu {
  private int qnts = 0;

  public void menuPrincipal() {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int opcao;
    ListaEncadeada listaJogadores = new ListaEncadeada();
    do {
      System.out.println("------------------------General------------------------");
      System.out.println("1- Cadastro de jogador");
      System.out.println("2-Jogar");
      System.out.println("3-Ver pontuação da partida");
      System.out.println("4-Ver pontuação geral");
      System.out.println("5-Sair");
      opcao = entrada.nextInt();
      switch (opcao) {
        case 1:
          System.out.println("---------------CADASTRO DE JOGADOR----------------");
          System.out.println("Digite o nome do jogador:");
          Jogador player = new Jogador();
          player.setNome(entrada.nextLine());
          entrada.nextLine();
          listaJogadores.incluirJogador(player);

          //inserir na lista encadeada e verificar
          break;
        //
        case 2:
          System.out.println("----------------JOGAR----------------");
          System.out.println("Jogador 1:");
          String player1, player2;
          player1 = entrada.nextLine();
          System.out.println("Jogador 2:");
          player2 = entrada.nextLine();
          break;
        //
        case 3:
          System.out.println("----------------PONTUAÇÃO DA PARTIDA----------------");
          break;
        //
        case 4:
          System.out.println("----------------PONTUAÇÃO GERAL----------------");
          System.out.println(
              "Jogador | Numero de jogos | Numero de vitórias | Empates | Pontos | Derrotas |");
          int i;
          for (i = 0; i < listaJogadores.getTamanho(); i++) {
            /*System.out.println(""+listaJogadores.get(i).getNome()+"|"+listaJogadores.get(i).getNumJogos()+"|"+listaJogadores.get(i).getNumWin()+"|"+listaJogadores.get(i).getEmpates()+"|"+listaJogadores.get(i).getPontos()+"|"+listaJogadores.get(i).getDerrotas());  */
          }

          System.out.println("");

          break;
        //
        case 5:
          System.out.println("SAINDO DO PROGRAMA...");
          break;

        //teste
        case 6:

          System.out.println(listaJogadores.get(0).getNome());
          break;
        //

      }
    } while (opcao != 5);
  }
}
```

no case 6 também tentei assim e não deu:

```
Jogador jogadori= new Jogador();
jogadori.setNome(listaJogadores.get(0).getNome());
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço! Não sei o porquê não estou conseguindo incluir os jogadores na lista.

Comment: Como foi definida a classe `Nodo` ? O que significa esse `return 2;` dentro do método `incluirJogador` ? "estou tentando imprimir [...]. (Mas não imprime nada)" - Mas o `case 6` apenas imprime o nó na posição `0` - `System.out.println(listaJogadores.get(0).getNome());`, para imprimir todos tem de transformar num laço.

Comment: Sim to tentando apenas cadastrar um (incluir) e mostrar na posição que ele foi incluido pra ver se ta dando certo. (é só um teste) o Return 2 eu ia fazer mais coisas do tipo pertencer e não... mas já mudei o método pra void.

Comment: Então esse `get(0)` não mostra nada é isso ? Tem como colocar uma versão testável do código ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está aqui:

```
player.setNome(entrada.nextLine());
entrada.nextLine();
```

Você na verdade inverteu as instruções. O primeiro `nextLine` é que apanha apenas o final de linha que sobrou do último `nextInt` acima e só o segundo `nextLine` é que apanha o texto correto para o nome do jogador.

Basta inverter para ficar assim:

```
entrada.nextLine();
player.setNome(entrada.nextLine());
```

Como já indiquei nos comentários, depois para poder mostrar todos os jogadores vai precisar de utilizar um laço/ciclo.

Tome nota que tem o mesmo problema no `case` `2` do `switch`:

```
String player1, player2;
player1 = entrada.nextLine(); // <--- aqui
```

Em que deve ter um `nextLine` vazio antes.

---

Se quiser aprofundar sobre este problema [veja esta pergunta do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262976/por-que-o-scanner-retorna-erro-em-algo-que-est%C3%A1-dentro-do-esperado)

Comment: Gostei de sua resposta! Me ajudou muito!!! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @YODA Sem problema, estamos cá para ajudar. :)

Answer (score -1):

Da uma olhada neste material. Vai resolver seus problemas sobre lista encadeada
[Caelum](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-estrutura-dados/listas-ligadas/)

```
    public class AlunoLista {
          private String nome;
          private int idade;
          private AlunoLista proximo;
    }
```

```
public class Celula {
  private Celula proxima;
  private Object elemento;

  public Celula(Celula proxima, Object elemento) {
    this.proxima = proxima;
    this.elemento = elemento;
  }

  public Celula(Object elemento) {
    this.elemento = elemento;
  }

  public void setProxima(Celula proxima) {
    this.proxima = proxima;
  }

  public Celula getProxima() {
    return proxima;
  }

  public Object getElemento() {
    return elemento;
  }
}
```

```
public class ListaLigada {

  private Celula primeira;

  private Celula ultima;

  public void adiciona(Object elemento) {}
  public void adiciona(int posicao, Object elemento) {}
  public Object pega(int posicao) {return null;}
  public void remove(int posicao){}
  public int tamanho() {return 0;}
  public boolean contem(Object o) {return false;}
}
```

```
public void adicionaNoComeco(Object elemento) {
    Celula nova = new Celula(this.primeira, elemento);
    this.primeira = nova;

    if(this.totalDeElementos == 0){
      // caso especial da lista vazia
      this.ultima = this.primeira;
    }
    this.totalDeElementos++;
  }
```

```
public void adiciona(int posicao, Object elemento) {
  if(posicao == 0){ // No começo.
    this.adicionaNoComeco(elemento);
  } else if(posicao == this.totalDeElementos){ // No fim.
    this.adiciona(elemento);
  } else {
    Celula anterior = this.pegaCelula(posicao - 1);
    Celula nova = new Celula(anterior.getProxima(), elemento);
    anterior.setProxima(nova);
    this.totalDeElementos++;
  }
}
```

```
public String toString() {

  // Verificando se a Lista está vazia
  if(this.totalDeElementos == 0){
    return "[]";
  }

  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("[");
  Celula atual = primeira;

  // Percorrendo até o penúltimo elemento.
  for (int i = 0; i 


private boolean posicaoOcupada(int posicao){
  return posicao >= 0 && posicao 


public Object pega(int posicao) {
  return this.pegaCelula(posicao).getElemento();
}

public int tamanho() {
    return this.totalDeElementos;
  }
}



public void removeDoComeco() {
  if (!this.posicaoOcupada(0)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Posição não existe");
  }

  this.primeira = this.primeira.getProxima();
  this.totalDeElementos--;

  if (this.totalDeElementos == 0) {
    this.ultima = null;
  }
}



public void removeDoFim() {
  if (!this.posicaoOcupada(this.totalDeElementos - 1)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Posição não existe");
  }
  if (this.totalDeElementos == 1) {
    this.removeDoComeco();
  } else {
    Celula penultima = this.ultima.getAnterior();
    penultima.setProxima(null);
    this.ultima = penultima;
    this.totalDeElementos--;
  }
}



public void remove(int posicao) {
  if (!this.posicaoOcupada(posicao)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Posição não existe");
  }

  if (posicao == 0) {
    this.removeDoComeco();
  } else if (posicao == this.totalDeElementos - 1) {
    this.removeDoFim();
  } else {
    Celula anterior = this.pegaCelula(posicao - 1);
    Celula atual = anterior.getProxima();
    Celula proxima = atual.getProxima();

    anterior.setProxima(proxima);
    proxima.setAnterior(anterior);

    this.totalDeElementos--;
  }
}



public boolean contem(Object elemento) {
  Celula atual = this.primeira;

  while (atual != null) {
    if (atual.getElemento().equals(elemento)) {
      return true;
    }
    atual = atual.getProxima();
  }
  return false;
}
```