# Como dar split em uma String que contém espaços em branco no começo?

Tags: java, string, regex

Para o problema em questão, preciso remover todos os caracteres especiais e espaços e contar as novas saídas possíveis. Minha intenção é separar a String com o método `split()`. Para isso, baseado em uma outra expressão que vi, criei essa:

```
String[] d = s.split("[,.!?'@_] *| +");
```

Ela funciona. O problema é que se tiverem muitos espaços em branco antes do início da expressão ela não exclui. Tentei colocar espaço antes, na expressão, mas não deu certo. Alguém pode me ajudar?
Segue o código completo:

```
        String s = "           YES      leading spaces        are valid,    problemsetters are         evillllll";
        String[] d = s.split("[,.!?'@_] *| +");
        int i, c = d.length;
        System.out.println(c);
        for(i = 0; i < d.length; i++){
            System.out.println(d[i]);
        }
```

A saída produzida é essa:

```
9

YES
leading
spaces
are
valid
problemsetters
are
evillllll
```

Mas precisa ser essa:

```
8
YES
leading
spaces
are
valid
problemsetters
are
evillllll
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Esse é um problema conhecido do `split` quando a `String` começa com espaços, [inclusive já discutido no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7961058).

A solução mais simples é usar o [método `trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()), que remove os espaços do começo e final da `String`, e em seguida fazer o `split`:

```
String[] d = s.trim().split("[,.!?'@_] *| +");
```

Com isso você terá a saída desejada (o array com 8 elementos).

Comment: Muito obrigada! ^_^

Answer (score 7):

Vamos ver este caso mais simples:

```
class TesteRegex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = " A B C ";
        String[] d = s.split(" ", 5);
        System.out.println(d.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("[" + d[i] + "]");
        } 
    }
}
```

Ele produz como saída:

```
5
[]    
[A]
[B]
[C]
[]
```

[**Veja isso rodando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/IGvxf4)

O problema é que o espaço é visto como um **separador**. Assim sendo, o primeiro espaço **separa** o início da `String` do `A`, o segundo espaço **separa** o `A` do `B`, o terceiro espaço **separa** o `B` do `C`, o quarto espaço **separa** o `C` do fim da string. Dessa forma, teríamos 5 partículas resultantes: o início, `A`, `B`, `C` e o final.

Entretanto, se você retirar o `, 5` do código acima, apenas as quatro primeiras irão vir. O motivo pode ser visto no [javadoc do método `split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) que diz isso:

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Traduzindo:

> Strings vazias no final portanto não são incluídas no array resultante.

Porém, não existe regra quanto a strings vazias no começo (*leading empty strings*), há regra apenas para as strings no final.

Olhando o código do método `split(String, int)`, ele se preocupa em remover as strings vazias no final quando o `limit` (que é o segundo parâmetro do `split`) é zero:

```
        // Add remaining segment
        if (!limited || list.size() < limit)
            list.add(substring(off, length()));
```

No método análogo da classe `java.util.regex.Pattern` também:

```
    // Add remaining segment
    if (!matchLimited || matchList.size() < limit)
        matchList.add(input.subSequence(index, input.length()).toString());
```

Mas ele não se preocupa em momento nenhum de fazer isso com as strings vazias no início.

Não sei ao certo qual é a razão para esse comportamento. Acho que deve ter alguma relação com [**isso**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262976/132), mas não tenho certeza. No entanto, seja qual for a motivação, esse é um comportamento proposital e não trata-se de algo acidental. Além disso, esse comportamento não poderia ser mudado devido a questões de compatibilidade.

Assim sendo, a solução é você usar um `trim()` ou então verificar se o primeiro elemento está em branco e ignorá-lo ou removê-lo se for esse o caso.

Comment: Muito obrigada! ^_^