# Como identificar um caracter de quebra de linha em C?

Tags: c, string, caracteres, quebras-de-linha

Problema: às vezes eu recebo uma entrada como

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*(e a entrada continua)*

outras vezes como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*(e a entrada continua)*

Ou seja, eu posso receber um inteiro, ou dois, ou três, e então depois receber uma string para fazer qualquer coisa.

**Meu problema:** Não consigo definir quando parar de receber os inteiros. Tentei identificando o caracter '\n', porém não está funcionando.

```
            while(lixo != '\n'){
                scanf("%d", &y);
                scanf("%c", &lixo);
                for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
                    if(!i && matriz[y][0]) break;
                    matriz[y][i] = 1;
                    inseticida += 2;
                }
            }
```

Como posso identificar essa quebra de linha para parar de receber os inteiros e sair do ciclo while?

Comment: O input pode ser `2 3 4` ou apenas `2` caso dê enter, é isso?

Comment: Isso, eu posso digitar 2 3*enter*, ou 2*enter*.

Comment: O seu erro é quase o mesmo disso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262976/132 - Só que o seu é em C ao invés de Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema é quase igual ao que foi delineado [**nesta outra pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262976/132). A única diferença é que o seu é em C, não em Java.

A abordagem da solução é a mesma. Você está lendo linhas contendo números. Isso é diferente de simplesmente ler números. Embora sejam coisas parecidas, há alguma diferença exatamente por causa das quebras-de-linha. Logo, para ler uma linha contendo um número, faça assim:

```
char linha[11];
fgets(linha, 10, stdin); // Lê a linha inteira.
sscanf(linha, "%d", &y); // Retira o número da linha lida.
```

Para retirar três números da linha lida:

```
sscanf(linha, "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c); // Retira três números da linha lida.
```

Para ler vários números de uma linha e processarmos eles a medida que formos lendo, fica mais complicado, mas podemos usar o `%n` que diz quantos caracteres foram lidos. Por exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char linha[10001];
    fgets(linha, 10000, stdin); // Lê a linha inteira.
    int pos = 0;
    while (1) {
        int y;
        int p;
        int ret = sscanf(&linha[pos], "%d%n", &y, &p); // Retira um número da linha lida.
        pos += p;
        if (ret == EOF) break;
        printf("%d ", y);
    }
    printf("fim");
}
```

Com esta entrada:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

A saída é essa:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 fim
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/3NqEsS)

Essas quatro linhas são o coração do negócio:

```
        int p;
        int ret = sscanf(&linha[pos], "%d%n", &y, &p); // Retira um número da linha lida.
        pos += p;
        if (ret == EOF) break;
```

Primeiro, o `%d` vai colocar o valor lido no endereço de `y`. Isso se algum valor puder ser lido. Se nenhum valor puder ser lido, `EOF` é retornado e o `break;` interrompe o `while`.

Se algum valor puder ser lido, o `%n` especifica que a quantidade de caracteres lidos é colocada no endereço de `p`. Isso daí é somado ao valor de `pos`. Desta forma, `&linha[pos]` correspode sempre a parte ainda não lida da linha.

Comment: o problema é que ele quer um input de `2 43 5` como por exemplo, o `sscanf` apenas ia retirar 1 numero

Comment: @FábioMorais Editado.

Comment: Não está a perceber, ele não sabe a quantidade que irá colocar, pode ser 1,2,3,4,5...etc é indefinido

Comment: @FábioMorais Resolvido.

Comment: Sim, agora já resolve o assunto, boa solução!

Comment: Pode explicar a linha ` int ret = sscanf(&linha[pos], "%d%n", &y, &p);` ? Achei essa linha bastante interessante, mas não estou a conseguir perceber.

Comment: Eu também gostaria de que explicasse como funciona a linha que o amigo acima citou.

Comment: @FábioMorais Editado com a explicação.

Comment: @WilliamPhilippe Editado com a explicação.

Answer (score 1):

```
int number;
char nl = 0;

while ( scanf("%d%c", &number, &nl) != EOF)
{
    printf("%d \n", number);//debug

    if (nl == '\n')
        break;
}
```

É um exemplo que penso que vá resultar, coloquei um print para dar um "debug" e ver o que acontecia, testei aqui e funcionou, me dê algum feedback.

Coloquei dessa maneira porque esse trecho de codigo penso que será fácil de ver o que está a fazer.

**[Codigo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/uaWAxW)**

```
char lixo = 0;

while(scanf("%d%c", &y, &lixo) != EOF)
{

    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        if(!i && matriz[y][0]) break;
        matriz[y][i] = 1;
        inseticida += 2;
    }
    if (lixo == '\n')
        break;
}
```

Comment: Isto funcionou! Obrigado.