# Estacionamento Pilha

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

A questão pede para usar pilha em um estacionamento,em que possui apenas uma entrada,que serve para saída também.
Já fiz 80% da questão,meu problema principal está sendo na contagem de quantas vezes o topo foi removido.Por favor,quem puder me ajudar,ficarei grato

```
 package estacionamento;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Estacionamento {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Pilha p = new Pilha(4);
      Pilha p2 = new Pilha(4);
      char mov = 0;
      int placa =0;
              Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
      for(int i = 0;i<p.ele.length;i++){
      do{
        System.out.println("Informe a movimentação do carro : ");
  mov=s.next().charAt(0);
     switch(mov){
         case 'E':
                 if(p.estaCheia()){
                     System.out.println("Estacionamento cheio!");    
                 }
                 else {
                     System.out.println("Por favor,informe a placa");
                  placa =s.nextInt();
              p.inserir(placa);
                     System.out.println(placa+" foi inserido");
                 }
            break;
         case 'S':
             System.out.println("Informe a posição do carro a ser retirado");
            int e = s.nextInt();
           while(i!=e){
               Object rem = p.remover();
               p2.inserir(rem);
           }

           while(p.inserir(p2.remover())){
           }
           ;
   }
       break;
   }  while(!p.estaCheia());
    }
            System.out.println(p);
}
```

### }

CLASSE PILHA
package estacionamento;

public class Pilha{

```
int topo;

T[] ele;





 public Pilha(int max){

        ele = (T[]) new Object[max];

        topo = -1;

    }

    public boolean estaCheia(){

        return topo == ele.length-1;

    }

    public boolean estaVazia(){

        return topo == -1;

    }

    public boolean inserir(T elem){

        if(!this.estaCheia()){

            topo++;

            ele[topo]= elem;

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

    public T remover(){



        if(!this.estaVazia()){



            return ele[topo--];



        }

        return null;

    }

      public String toString(){



            Pilha p2 = new Pilha( this.ele.length );

            String s = "[";
            while( !this.estaVazia() ){
                T a = this.remover();
               p2.inserir(a);
               s += a + ",";
            }
            s += "]";
            return s;
        }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o código da classe `Pilha`? Por que a placa do carro é um inteiro ao invés de uma `String`? Vejo que você tem duas pilhas e só a `p` é que você usa para contabilizar se o estacionamento está cheio, o `p2` não deveria ser também considerado?

Comment: Boa noite,eu usei um int,pois a String não estava aceitando dentro do swtich...E a segunda pilha serve para reorganizar os carros.A primeira pilha,emplilha normalmente e a segunda é uma auxiliar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A indentação do seu código está uma bagunça. Reindentando o seu código, chega-se nisso:

```java
package estacionamento;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Estacionamento {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pilha p = new Pilha(4);
        Pilha p2 = new Pilha(4);
        char mov = 0;
        int placa = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < p.ele.length; i++) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Informe a movimentação do carro : ");
                mov = s.next().charAt(0);
                switch(mov) {
                    case 'E':
                        if (p.estaCheia()) {
                            System.out.println("Estacionamento cheio!");
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Por favor,informe a placa");
                            placa = s.nextInt();
                            p.inserir(placa);
                            System.out.println(placa + " foi inserido");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'S':
                        System.out.println("Informe a posição do carro a ser retirado");
                        int e = s.nextInt();
                        while (i != e) {
                            Object rem = p.remover();
                            p2.inserir(rem);
                        }
                        while(p.inserir(p2.remover())) {
                        }
                        ;
                }
                break;
            } while (!p.estaCheia());
        }
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

```java
package estacionamento;

public class Pilha<T> {
    int topo;
    T[] ele;

    public Pilha(int max) {
        ele = (T[]) new Object[max];
        topo = -1;
    }

    public boolean estaCheia(){
        return topo == ele.length-1;
    }

    public boolean estaVazia() {
        return topo == -1;
    }

    public boolean inserir(T elem) {
        if (!this.estaCheia()) {
            topo++;
            ele[topo]= elem;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public T remover() {
        if (!this.estaVazia()) {
            return ele[topo--];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String toString() {
        Pilha p2 = new Pilha(this.ele.length);
        String s = "[";
        while (!this.estaVazia()) {
            T a = this.remover();
            p2.inserir(a);
            s += a + ",";
        }
        s += "]";
        return s;
    }
}
```

2. A implementação do método `toString()` da classe `Pilha` é uma das piores que já vi, pois **ele destrói a pilha em questão**. Isso está muito muito MUITO errado! Você está retirando todos os elementos da pilha e os salvando em `p2`. Ocorre que `p2` vai para o coletor de lixo quando o `toString()` termina. Chamar o método `toString()` **NUNCA** deveria produzir efeitos colaterais seja no objeto no qual ele foi chamado ou seja em qualquer outro.
3. Arrays não se dão bem com tipos genéricos e há (ou ao menos deveria haver) poucas razões para se querer usar arrays ao invés de listas. Use listas.
4. Ao usar uma lista dentro da classe `Pilha`, você não vai mais precisar da variável `topo`.
5. Muito dificilmente você vai ter interesse em usar a visibilidade de pacote, então não esqueça o modificador `private` ou `public`.
6. Use nomes de variáveis descritivos. Não é isso que está ocorrendo com o `ele` e com `mov`, por exemplo.

Com isso, o código da sua classe `Pilha` fica assim:

```java
package estacionamento;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Pilha<T> {
    private final int max;
    private final List<T> elementos;

    public Pilha(int max) {
        this.max = max;
        this.elementos = new ArrayList<>(max);
    }

    public boolean estaCheia() {
        return max == elementos.size();
    }

    public boolean estaVazia() {
        return elementos.isEmpty();
    }

    public boolean inserir(T elem) {
        if (this.estaCheia()) return false;
        elementos.add(elem);
        return true;
    }

    public T remover() {
        return this.estaVazia()) ? null : elementos.remove(elementos.size() - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return elementos.toString();
    }
}
```

7. Evite declarar variáveis em um escopo maior do que o necessário. Isso está ocorrendo com as variáveis `mov` que poderia ser declarada apenas dentro do `do-while` e `placa` que poderia ser declarada apenas dentro do `else`.
8. Quando o seu programa começa a ficar complicado (`switch` dentro de `do-while` dentro de `for`) é uma boa ideia dividí-lo em classes e em funções menores. Em especial, se você ver que você pode ter um objeto do tipo `Estacionamento` e separar o que há no `case 'E'` e no `case 'S'` em métodos menores, as coisas vão ficar bem mais fáceis.
9. Não viole o encapsulamento de objetos com coisas como `p.ele.length`. Aqui, `p` é um dado interno do `main` e até aqui, tudo bem o `main` acessá-lo. Entretanto, `ele` é um dado interno de `p`, e portanto, neste ponto, o `main` está acessando um dado interno de um dado interno. Acessar o dado interno de um dado interno é uma violação do encapsulamento.
10. O motivo pelo qual você não consegue usar o `Scanner` para ler texto é [este daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262976/132).
11. Se sua classe `Pilha` é genérica, então você deveria utilizá-la como tal dentro do método `main`. Utilizar classes genéricas sem os tipos genéricos é uma má prática de programação.
12. Você só precisa da sua `p2` enquanto estiver removendo carros. Assim sendo é conveniente que a `p2` só seja criada e utilizada nessa ocasião.
13. Há um `break` dentro do `do-while` que faz com que ele pare sempre logo na primeira interação. Acho que isso está errado e era para o `break` estar dentro do `case 'S'`. Novamente, este tipo de confusão é comum quando você não indenta o seu código.
14. Não tem sentido rodar o `for` quatro vezes, considerando que o que ocorre no `do-while` poderia adicionar e retirar carros a vontade (não fosse o problema do item 13). Faz muito menos sentido ainda usar o índice do `for` na remoção de carros.
15. O `while(p.inserir(p2.remover()))` vai dar problema quando o `remover` retornar `null`.
16. Saber a hora que o programa deve parar, considerando o `for` e o `do-while` é meio complicado. Melhor fazer o programa parar apenas quando o usuário pedir por isso (por exemplo, digitando <kbd>X</kbd> ao invés de <kbd>S</kbd> ou <kbd>E</kbd>).
17. Tentar retirar um carro quando a pilha já está vazia, não vai dar certo. O mesmo se você quiser tirar o terceiro carro se só houver um, ou algo assim. Com um `if` a mais, podemos nos proteger disso.
18. Para contar quantas vezes o topo foi removido, basta você incrementar um contador dentro do `while` que remove os carros.

Seu código `Estacionamento` fica assim:

```java
package estacionamento;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Estacionamento {

    private final Scanner scan;
    private final Pilha<String> p1;
    private final Pilha<String> p2;
    private int remocoesSofridas;

    public Estacionamento(int max) {
        this.scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.p1 = new Pilha<>(max);
        this.p2 = new Pilha<>(max);
        this.remocoesSofridas = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Estacionamento e = new Estacionamento(4);
        while (e.mover()) {}
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("Total de vezes que o topo foi removido: " + e.remocoesSofridas);
    }

    private boolean mover() {
        System.out.println("Informe a movimentação do carro: ");
        char mov = scan.nextLine().charAt(0);
        switch(mov) {
            case 'E':
                e.adicionar();
                return true;
            case 'S':
                e.retirar();
                return true;
            case 'X':
                return false;
            default:
                System.out.println("Desculpe, não entendi isso.");
                return true;
        }
    }

    private void adicionar() {
        if (p1.estaCheia()) {
            System.out.println("Estacionamento cheio!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Por favor, informe a placa: ");
            String placa = scan.nextLine();
            p1.inserir(placa);
            System.out.println(placa + " foi inserido.");
        }
    }

    private void retirar() {
        Pilha<String> p2 = new Pilha<>(p1.tamanho());
        System.out.println("Informe a posição do carro a ser retirado: ");
        int posicao = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        if (posicao + 1 >= p1.tamanho()) {
            System.out.println("Não podemos retirar o carro " + i + " pois o último é o " + (p1.tamanho() - 1) + ".");
            return;
        }
        while (p1.tamanho() > posicao) {
            String rem = p1.remover();
            p2.inserir(rem);
            remocoesSofridas++;
        }
        String placaRemovida = p2.remover();
        while (!p2.estaVazia()) {
            p1.inserir(p2.remover());
        }
        System.out.println("O carro removido foi o " + placaRemovida);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return p1.toString();
    }

    public boolean estaCheia() {
        return p1.estaCheia();
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas mano...o código da Pilha é o que o professor mandou...

Comment: Obrigado por responder