# JAVA - Pula o input de uma das variáveis e encerra o código

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um código de leitura simples para cadastro de produtos. Quando estou inserindo as informações em cada variável, uma variável com tipo primitivo double ou int, ele pula a outra que seria uma stringe encerra meu código.

Abaixo código:

public class Programa {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ProdutoCarrinho produtoCarrinho = new ProdutoCarrinho();
    ProdutoCarrinho produtoCarrinho2 = new ProdutoCarrinho();
    //ProdutoCarrinho produtoCarrinho3 = new ProdutoCarrinho();


    System.out.println("Informe Id do produto:");
    produtoCarrinho.id = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Informe nome do produto:");
    produtoCarrinho.nome = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Informe a quantidade:");
    produtoCarrinho.quantidade = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Informe o valor do produto:");
    produtoCarrinho.valor = scanner.nextDouble();



    // 2º carrinho

    System.out.println("Informe Id do produto:");
    produtoCarrinho2.id = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Informe nome do produto:");
    produtoCarrinho2.nome = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Informe a quantidade:");
    produtoCarrinho2.quantidade = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Informe o valor do produto:");
    produtoCarrinho2.valor = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("ID do produto: " + produtoCarrinho.id);
    System.out.println("Nome do produto: " + produtoCarrinho.nome);
    System.out.println("O valor do produto: " + produtoCarrinho.valor);
    System.out.println("Quantidade total: " + produtoCarrinho.quantidade);
```

Aqui um exemplo da resposta na hora dos inputs.

Informe Id do produto:
1
Informe nome do produto:
note
Informe a quantidade:
1
Informe o valor do produto:
3000
Informe Id do produto:
Informe nome do produto:

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Por que o Scanner retorna erro em algo que está dentro do esperado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262976/por-que-o-scanner-retorna-erro-em-algo-que-est%c3%a1-dentro-do-esperado)

Comment: Pessoal obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você teria que postar a classe ProdutoCarrinho também e você poderia inserir a operacao toda em um bloco `try...catch` para ver se há algum erro específico em relacao à entrada. Mas o problema está no `scanner.int()`. Essa operacao nao consome a linha de entrada. Na próxima chamada de `scanner.nextLine()` você vai receber uma String vazia do `scanner.int()` anterior. Você poderia modificar o seu código para somente usar o `scanner.nextLine()` e fazer as conversoes necessárias:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Informe Id do produto:");
String idLendo = scanner.nextLine();
int id = Integer.parseInt(idLendo);

System.out.println("Informe nome do produto:");
String nome = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("Informe a quantidade:");
String quantidadeLendo = scanner.nextLine();
int quantidade = Integer.parseInt(quantidadeLendo);

System.out.println("Informe o valor do produto:");
String valorLendo = scanner.nextLine();
Double valor = Double.parseDouble(valorLendo);

System.out.println(id + " " + nome + " " + quantidade + " " + valor);
```

--- Saída

```
Informe Id do produto:
1
Informe nome do produto:
nome
Informe a quantidade:
23
Informe o valor do produto:
3000
1 nome 23 3000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Depois de ler o `double` com `scanner.nextDouble()` utilize `scanner.next()` em vez de `scanner.nextLine()`.

```java
...
System.out.println("Informe Id do produto:");
produtoCarrinho2.id = scanner.next();

System.out.println("Informe nome do produto:");
produtoCarrinho2.nome = scanner.next();
...
```