# Carrinho de compras Java

Tags: java

Tenho dúvidas quanto a criação de um carrinho de compras, consegui até aqui: Informar o nome do produto, 
Preço do produto
Quantidade; aí existe a soma e a pergunta se que realizar outra compra, se for "N" ele finaliza, caso contrário ele reinicia.

Depois tem que ser informado um ciclo e depois somar todos os valores dividindo em dinheiro ou cartão.

```
package problema01;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author VAGNER.MATOS
 */
public class Problema01 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

        double num, preço;
        String nome;
        String nome2;
        char resposta;

            System.out.println("Informe o Produto:");// Usuario digita o nome do produto
            nome = ler.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Digite o preço do Produto");// usuario digita o preço
            preço = ent.nextDouble(); 
            System.out.println("Digite a quantidade do Produto"); // usuario digita a quantidade do produto
            num = ent.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("A Quantidade de produtos é "+num+"\nTotal a pagar é R$"+num*preço+"\n\nObrigado por comprar "+nome); // Resumo

            //Nova Compra        
            System.out.println("\nRealzar outra compra? (S/N): "); //entrada de dados (lendo um caractere)
            resposta = (char)System.in.read();
                if ((resposta == 'S') || (resposta == 's'));
{
                System.out.println("\n\"Nova compra\"\n");
                System.out.println("Favor iniciar com as informações\n");
                System.out.println("Informe o Produto:");
                nome2 = ler.nextLine();//Novo produto
                System.out.println("Digite o preço do Produto");
                preço = ent.nextDouble(); // usuario digita o preço              
                System.out.println("Digite a quantidade do Produto");
                num = ent.nextDouble(); // usuario digita a quantidade do produto
                System.out.println("A Quantidade de produtos é " + num + "\nTotal a pagar é R$"+ num*preço +"\n\nObrigado por comprar " + nome2);
}               System.out.println("\n\n\"Volte sempre!\"\n\n");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não faz sentido criar dois [`Scanner`'s](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) que lêem do mesmo lugar (no caso, do [`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#in)). Use um só.

Outro detalhe é esse ponto-e-vírgula depois do `if`:

```
if ((resposta == 'S') || (resposta == 's'));
                                           ^ esse aqui
```

Quando você faz isso, está dizendo que dentro do `if` tem um bloco vazio. Ou seja, se a resposta for `S` ou `s`, você não faz nada. E todo o trecho que vem depois não faz parte do `if` e é executado sempre. Retire esse `;` daí.

Não entendi porque a quantidade deve ser um `double`. Existe a possibilidade de alguém comprar algo como "2,6 produtos"? Se não existir, mude o tipo da variável para `int`.

E se está usando um [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html), não há motivo para misturar as leituras com [`System.in.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read()).

Outro detalhe é que se você quer repetir várias vezes a mesma coisa, tem que usar um *loop* (neste caso eu usaria um `while`, por exemplo).
Enfim, uma alternativa seria:

```
Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Informe o Produto:");// Usuario digita o nome do produto
    String nome = ent.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Digite o preço do Produto");// usuario digita o preço
    double preço = ent.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Digite a quantidade do Produto"); // usuario digita a quantidade do produto
    int num = ent.nextInt();
    ent.nextLine(); // consumir o ENTER, para não atrapalhar a próxima leitura: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262976/112052

    System.out.println("A Quantidade de produtos é " + num + "\nTotal a pagar é R$" + num * preço + "\n\nObrigado por comprar " + nome); // Resumo

    // Nova Compra
    System.out.println("\nRealzar outra compra? (S/N): "); // entrada de dados (lendo um caractere)
    String resposta = ent.nextLine();
    if ("n".equalsIgnoreCase(resposta))
        break; // sai do while(true)

    System.out.println("\n\"Nova compra\"\n");
    System.out.println("Favor iniciar com as informações\n");
}
System.out.println("\n\n\"Volte sempre!\"\n\n");
```

---

Claro que dá para melhorar mais. Se não for digitado um número, [`nextDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) e [`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) dão erro. Além disso, esses métodos não consomem a quebra de linha, e na próxima vez que você chamar [`nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()), o resultado será inesperado (por isso há a chamada extra de `nextLine` para consumir a quebra de linha, [conforme explicado em detalhes aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262976/112052)).

Em vez de `System.in.read` eu usei o `Scanner`, e fiz a comparação *case insensitive* para decidir se saio ou não do `while`. Mas eu só verifico se foi digitado "n", então se for digitado qualquer outra coisa, ele prossegue.

Enfim, uma alternativa um pouco melhor é criar métodos específicos para validar cada um desses casos:

```
double lerPreco(Scanner sc, String mensagem) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(mensagem);
        try {
            return Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Número inválido");
        }
    }
}

int lerQuantidade(Scanner sc, String mensagem) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(mensagem);
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Número inválido");
        }
    }
}

String lerOpcao(Scanner sc, String mensagem) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(mensagem);
        String opcao = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        if ("s".equals(opcao) || "n".equals(opcao))
            return opcao;
        else
            System.out.println("A opção deve ser S ou N");
    }
}
```

Aí é só usar esses métodos no *loop* principal. E como você disse que quer calcular o total de todas as compras, basta criar uma variável nova para isso e ir somando dentro do *loop*:

```
Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);
double total = 0;
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Informe o Produto:");// Usuario digita o nome do produto
    String nome = ent.nextLine();
    double preço = lerPreco(ent, "Digite o preço do Produto");
    int num = lerQuantidade(ent, "Digite a quantidade do Produto");
    double valor = num * preço;

    System.out.printf("A Quantidade de produtos é %d\nTotal a pagar é R$%.2f\n\nObrigado por comprar %s\n", num, valor, nome);
    total += valor;

    // Nova Compra
    String resposta = lerOpcao(ent, "\nRealzar outra compra? (S/N): ");
    if ("n".equalsIgnoreCase(resposta))
        break; // sai do while(true)

    System.out.println("\n\"Nova compra\"\n");
    System.out.println("Favor iniciar com as informações\n");
}
System.out.printf("Total das compras: R$%.2f\n", total);
System.out.println("\n\n\"Volte sempre!\"\n\n");
```

Também usei [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) para formatar o valor sempre com duas casas decimais. Se bem que, se for trabalhar com valores monetários, [é melhor não usar `double`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5746/112052).

Answer (score 0):

Então, sua pergunta está um pouco complicada de entender, mas pelo que eu li, você quer trabalhar com uma quantidade dinâmica de informações, ou seja, o usuário vai continuar entrando com os dados, até ele decidir parar, que seria a entrada 'N'.

Para esses tipos de situações uma forma de resolver é utilizando uma estrutura de repetição como o **while**, ou seja:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String nome;
double preco;
double num;

char resposta = 'S';

while (resposta=='S'){
  #Entradas do usuário aqui
}
```

Perceba que só houve a necessidade de um único **Scanner** para trabalhar com as entradas, além disso, eu já inicializei a variável **resposta** pra poder entrar no loop que irá continuar **até resposta == 'N'**.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito obrigado, como falei sou novato em programação, mas sua ajuda foi fundamental para meu projeto! Consegui montar uma estrutura while, mas ainda tenho que fazer o somatório no cartão e dinheiro, vou ver como ficou seus códigos aqui. Valeu!

Comment: Eu que agradeço, qualquer outra dúvida pode jogar aqui, valeu!!

Comment: Boa tarde! Ainda não consegui testar o codigo, como informei, estou iniciando em programação, então preciso do codigo completo para conseguir testar