# Manipulação de matrizes em JAVA

Tags: java, matriz

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um sistema bem simples de estoque onde os itens serao armazenados em uma matriz segue codigo:

```
package main;

import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IncluirItem{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] itens = new String[2][5];
        String[] campos = new String[7];
        int opcao = 0;
        int remover;
        int verificar = 0;
        int adcionar = 0;
        int tamanho = 2;
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        campos [1] = "Nome";
        campos [2] = "Codigo de barras";
        campos [3] = "quantidade";
        campos [4] = "validade";
        campos [5] = "data de entrada";
        
        do {
            System.out.println("\n\n### Sistema de estoque - simplificado ###");
            System.out.println("=========================================");
            System.out.println("      |     1 - Adcionar itens   |");
            System.out.println("      |     2 - Excluir itens    |");
            System.out.println("      |     3 - Mostrar itens    |");
            System.out.println("      |     0 - Sair             |");
            System.out.println("=========================================\n");
            
            System.out.println("Escolha uma opcao: ");
            opcao = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\n");
            
            switch (opcao) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Cadastro de itens: ");
                //Adciona itens 
                for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Adcionar item? ");
                    System.out.println("1 para sim \n2 para nao: ");
                    adcionar = sc.nextInt();
                    if (adcionar == 1) {
                        System.out.printf("%d. item \n", (i+1));
                        verificar = verificar + 1;
                        for (int j=0; j < 5; j++) { 
                            System.out.printf("%s ", campos[j+1]);
                            System.out.printf("= ", i,(j+1));
                            itens[i][j] = sc.next();
                            
                        }
                        System.out.printf("\n");
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                    
                break;
            case 2:
                //Remove itens
                System.out.println("Exclusao de itens: ");
                if(verificar > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {    
                        System.out.printf("%d. item \n", (i+1));
                        System.out.printf("ID do produto= 00%d \n", (i+1));
                        System.out.printf("\n");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Nenhum item listado!");
                }
                System.out.println("\nEscolha o numero do item a ser removido: \n");
                remover = sc.nextInt();
                for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {
                    if(remover == 2) {
                    itens[i] = itens[i-1];
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                //Mostra itens
                if(verificar > 0) {
                    
                        for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {    
                            if (verificar == 2) {
                            System.out.printf("%d. item \n", (i+1));
                            System.out.printf("ID do produto= 00%d \n", (i+1));
                            for (int j=0; j < 5; j++) { 
                                System.out.printf("%s ", campos[j+1]);
                                System.out.printf("= %s \n", itens [i][j]);
                            }
                            System.out.printf("\n");
                        }
                        else {
                                    itens = Arrays.copyOf(itens, tamanho - 1);
                                    verificar = 0;
                                    System.out.printf("%d. item \n", (i+1));
                                    System.out.printf("ID do produto= 00%d \n", (i+1));
                                    for (int j=0; j < 5; j++) { 
                                        System.out.printf("%s ", campos[j+1]);
                                        System.out.printf("= %s \n", itens [i][j]);
                                    }
                                    System.out.printf("\n");
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Nenhum item listado!");
                }
                
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Opção Inválida!");
                break;
            }
        } while(opcao != 0);
    }
}
```

Minha duvida é a seguinte, eu quero excluir uma posicao da matriz, exemplo: registrei dois itens, na coluna um e coluna dois da matriz e gostaria de remover a coluna um da lista, como realizo essa função, e outra coisa, eu gostaria de quando eu inserisse pela segunda vez algum item a matriz começasse na proxima possicao vazia, atualmente se eu pedir para inserir um novo item a matriz começa da primeira posicao e assim apaga os elementos ja inseridos.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays têm tamanho fixo e não existe uma forma de apagar uma posição específica do mesmo. O máximo que daria para fazer é setar a posição com `null`, mas aí você teria que verificar se a posição é nula antes de tentar usá-la.

Mas sinceramente, arrays não são a melhor forma de fazer o que você quer. Muito menos um array de strings. Mas vamos por partes.

---

Se um item pode ter várias informações diferentes, agrupe-as em uma classe. Algo assim:

```
public class Item {
    private String nome;
    private String codigoDeBarras;
    private int quantidade;
    private int validade;
    private String dataEntrada;

    public Item(String nome, String codigoDeBarras, int quantidade, int validade, String dataEntrada) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.codigoDeBarras = codigoDeBarras;
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
        this.validade = validade;
        this.dataEntrada = dataEntrada;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    // demais getters e setters, etc
}
```

Coloquei os campos como `String` e `int` só como exemplo. Não sei se a validade é de fato um número - como "30" para dizer que vale 30 dias, por exemplo - ou se deveria ser uma data), e a data de entrada poderia ser um [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), ou [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), em vez de `String`. Mas o código acima é só para exemplificar mesmo.

Criei um *getter* para o nome, e você pode fazer o mesmo para os demais campos. Também é interessante ler [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/112052) para entender que nem sempre você é obrigado a criar *getters* e *setters* para tudo (mas no exemplo abaixo, vamos supor que criei todos os *getters*).

---

Agora que já temos uma classe que representa o item, podemos fazer o cadastro. Como ele é dinâmico (posso adicionar e remover itens à vontade), usar array não é uma boa opção, pois como já disse, ele tem tamanho fixo. Mas a lista de itens pode aumentar e diminuir conforme o usuário vai digitando as opções, então é melhor usar uma estrutura que possa ser modificada conforme a necessidade, como por exemplo um [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Ficaria assim:

```
public class CadastroItem {
    private List<Item> itens; // lista contendo os itens

    public CadastroItem() {
        // cadastro começa vazio - cria uma lista de itens sem nenhum elemento
        this.itens = new ArrayList<Item>();
    }

    public void adicionar(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.println("Adicionar item? ");
        System.out.println("1 para sim \n2 para nao: ");
        if (sc.nextInt() == 1) {
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.printf("%d. item \n", itens.size());
            System.out.print("nome: ");
            String nome = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("código de barras: ");
            String codigoBarras = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("quantidade: ");
            int qtd = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("validade: ");
            int validade = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("data de entrada: ");
            String dataEntrada = sc.nextLine();
            // adiciona o item
            itens.add(new Item(nome, codigoBarras, qtd, validade, dataEntrada));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void remover(Scanner sc) {
        if (this.itens.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Não há itens a serem removidos");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Itens existentes:");
        for (int i = 0; i < this.itens.size(); i++) {
            Item item = this.itens.get(i);
            System.out.printf("%d - %s\n", i, item.getNome());
        }
        System.out.println("\nEscolha o número do item a ser removido: ");
        int posicao = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        if (posicao < 0 || posicao >= this.itens.size()) {
            System.out.println("Posição inválida");
        } else {
            this.itens.remove(posicao);
        }
    }

    public void mostrar() {
        if (this.itens.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Não há itens a serem mostrados");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Itens existentes:");
            for (int i = 0; i < this.itens.size(); i++) {
                Item item = this.itens.get(i);
                System.out.printf("%d - nome=%s, código de barras=%s, quantidade=%d, validade=%d, data de entrada=%s\n", i, item.getNome(),
                                  item.getCodigoDeBarras(), item.getQuantidade(), item.getValidade(), item.getDataEntrada());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Em alguns casos eu chamei [`nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) sem atribuir a nenhuma variável, porque os  métodos que lêem números, como [`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--), não consomem a quebra de linha (o <kbd>ENTER</kbd>), então ao chamar `nextLine` logo em seguida poderia não funcionar corretamente ([leia aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262976/112052) para entender melhor).

Repare que separei cada operação em um método, deixando as coisas um pouco mais organizadas. Assim, o `main` ficaria:

```
CadastroItem cadastro = new CadastroItem();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("\n\n### Sistema de estoque - simplificado ###");
    System.out.println("=========================================");
    System.out.println("      |     1 - Adicionar itens  |");
    System.out.println("      |     2 - Excluir itens    |");
    System.out.println("      |     3 - Mostrar itens    |");
    System.out.println("      |     0 - Sair             |");
    System.out.println("=========================================\n");

    System.out.println("Escolha uma opcao: ");
    int opcao = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
    if (opcao == 0)
        break; // se for zero, sai do while (nem testa as demais opções)

    switch (opcao) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Cadastro de itens: ");
            cadastro.adicionar(sc);
            break;
        case 2:
            // Remove itens
            System.out.println("Exclusao de itens: ");
            cadastro.remover(sc);
            break;
        case 3:
            // Mostra itens
            cadastro.mostrar();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Opção Inválida!");
            break;
    }
}
```

---

Claro que ainda dá para melhorar. Se não for digitado um número, `nextInt` dá erro e o programa para de executar. Então na classe `CadastroItem` você poderia ter um método que valida se foi digitado um número de fato:

```
public class CadastroItem {
    ...

    private int lerNumero(Scanner sc, String mensagem) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(mensagem);
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Não foi digitado um número, tente novamente");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assim, você não precisa mais ter as chamadas de `nextLine` logo depois de `nextInt`, e ficaria assim:

```
public void adicionar(Scanner sc) {
    System.out.println("Adicionar item? ");
    System.out.println("1 para sim \n2 para nao: ");
    if (sc.nextInt() == 1) {
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("%d. item \n", itens.size());
        System.out.print("nome: ");
        String nome = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("código de barras: ");
        String codigoBarras = sc.nextLine();
        int qtd = lerNumero(sc, "quantidade:");
        int validade = lerNumero(sc, "validade");
        System.out.print("data de entrada: ");
        String dataEntrada = sc.nextLine();
        // adiciona o item
        itens.add(new Item(nome, codigoBarras, qtd, validade, dataEntrada));
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public void remover(Scanner sc) {
    if (this.itens.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Não há itens a serem removidos");
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Itens existentes:");
    for (int i = 0; i < this.itens.size(); i++) {
        Item item = this.itens.get(i);
        System.out.printf("%d - %s\n", i, item.getNome());
    }
    int posicao = lerNumero(sc, "\nEscolha o numero do item a ser removido: ");
    if (posicao < 0 || posicao >= this.itens.size()) {
        System.out.println("Posição inválida");
    } else {
        this.itens.remove(posicao);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pra você remover a coluna um, deveria setar os valores dessa coluna como 'null' ou algo do tipo, servindo como indicativo pra você mesmo de que esta coluna esta excluída. Já para adicionar os valores na próxima coluna, é possível rodar a matriz pra descobrir o tamanho e inserir no próximo índice, é possível verificar se a próxima posição existe (try catch é importante nesse caso) Dentre outras soluções... Porém na minha opinião, você se encontra no momento perfeito pra expandir seus horizontes e compreender ArrayList, pois provavelment essas funções já são nativas.

Answer (score -1):

Para você controlar a linha que já foi registrada um item é bem simples.
Faz uma variável contadora começando do 0, exp: **int c = 0;**
No case 1 tu coloca assim: **for (int i = c; i < (número de linhas da matriz); i++) {**.
E depois que sair desse **for**: "**for (int j=0; j < 5; j++) {}**" você coloca **c++**;
Assim sempre você vai pra uma nova linha que não foi registrado nada.

Comment: Essa solucao funcionou para mim, preciso agora excluir a posicao do vetor =(