# Problema ao ler strings e números em sequência com Scanner

Tags: java, scanner

Eu me deparei com esse problema no código na hora em que o programa vai ler o segundo nome e a nota do segundo nome, ou seja, o nome do segundo aluno e a sua nota. Podem me explicar oque aconteceu ?

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

String []nome = new String [5];
int []notas = new int [5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     System.out.println("Nome " + (i+1));
     nome[i] = teclado.nextLine();
     
     System.out.println("Nota " + (i+1));
     notas[i] = teclado.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema acontece por causa [disso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262976/112052).

Basicamente, `nextInt` só lê o mínimo necessário para que se tenha um número inteiro. Por isso ele não consome a quebra de linha (o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> que o usuário digita), e esta é consumida pela próxima chamada de `nextLine` (ou seja, o segundo nome será uma string vazia, já que só tem a quebra de linha para ser lida e será interpretado como uma linha vazia).

A solução é usar `nextLine` em ambos os casos, e em seguida converter a `String` para `int`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println("Nome " + (i + 1));
    nome[i] = teclado.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Nota " + (i + 1));
    notas[i] = Integer.parseInt(teclado.nextLine());
}
```

Outra opção é chamar `nextLine` logo em seguida, para forçar a leitura da quebra de linha, assim ela não interfere na próxima leitura do nome:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println("Nome " + (i + 1));
    nome[i] = teclado.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Nota " + (i + 1));
    notas[i] = teclado.nextInt();
    teclado.nextLine(); // <-- aqui
}
```

---

Vale notar que tanto o seu código quanto o meu acima darão erro se não for digitado um número. Se quiser validar, basta fazer um *loop* que fica pedindo que digite novamente enquanto não for um número:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println("Nome " + (i + 1));
    nome[i] = teclado.nextLine();

    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Nota " + (i + 1));
            notas[i] = Integer.parseInt(teclado.nextLine());
            break; // se chegou aqui, é número, interrompe o while
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Não foi digitado um número");
        }
    }
}
```

---

O mesmo problema acontece caso sejam usados outros métodos que não consomem a quebra de linha, como `nextDouble`, `nextLong`, `nextFloat`, etc.