# Erro parseException

Tags: java

Estou com um problema sobre DATE. Esta dando erro na linha 58 sobre:
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
at exsecao14a.ExSecao14A.main(ExSecao14A.java:58)
C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2rc\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 14 segundos)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    
    Scanner dados = new Scanner(System.in);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    List<Product> pdc = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.print("Entre com o numero de produto: ");
    int numeroP = dados.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i <= numeroP; i++) {
        System.out.println("Produto #" + i + " Data:");
        System.out.print("Comum, usado ou importado (c/u/i)? ");
        char cui = dados.next().charAt(0);

        System.out.print("Nome: ");
        dados.next();
        String nome = dados.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Preco: ");
        double preco = dados.nextDouble();

        if (cui == 'i') {
            System.out.println("Taxa alfandega: ");
            double taxa = dados.nextDouble();
            pdc.add(new ImportedProduct(taxa, nome, preco));

        } else if (cui == 'u') {
            System.out.print("Data de fabricação: dd/mm/yyyy: ");
            dados.next();
            String formatoNormal = dados.nextLine();
            Date formato = sdf.parse(formatoNormal); // ESSA É A LINHA 58

            pdc.add(new UsedProduct(formato, nome, preco));

        } else if (cui == 'c') {
            pdc.add(new Product(nome, preco));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: O que acontece se você retirar  a linha "dados.next();", duas linhas antes da linha 58?

Comment: data Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
Data de fabricação: dd/mm/yyyy:  at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
 at exsecao14a.ExSecao14A.main(ExSecao14A.java:58) @JoãoVictorSierra

Comment: ele "pula" a linha em que voce scaneia o formatoNormal né? o que eu imagino é que ele esteja consumindo um enter que ficou pendurado em alguma das outras leituras do scanner, a string vai ficar vazia e por consequencia uma string vazia ao tentar ser parseada da o exception

Comment: System.out.print("Data de fabricação: dd/mm/aaaa: ");
                Date formato = sdf.parse(dados.next());
Eu fiz isso e resolveu, Obrigado a todos

Answer (score 1):

O problema é basicamente o que está descrito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262976/112052): ao misturar chamadas de `nextLine` e `next` com `nextInt` e `nextDouble` pode causar alguns problemas inesperados. Isso porque métodos que lêem números, como `nextInt` e `nextDouble`, não consomem a quebra de linha (que corresponde ao <kbd>ENTER</kbd> que o usuário digita). Então se você chama `nextLine` logo depois de um `nextInt` ou `nextDouble`, ele consome a quebra de linha e o resultado é uma string vazia.

É isso que a exceção está reclamando, que você passou uma string vazia para `parse`.

Uma solução é forçar o `Scanner` a consumir a quebra de linha, chamando `nextLine` logo depois de ler o número (e remover as chamadas a `next`):

```
int numeroP = dados.nextInt();
dados.nextLine(); // <-------- aqui

for (int i = 1; i <= numeroP; i++) {
    System.out.println("Produto #" + i + " Data:");
    System.out.print("Comum, usado ou importado (c/u/i)? ");
    char cui = dados.nextLine().charAt(0);

    System.out.print("Nome: ");
    String nome = dados.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Preco: ");
    double preco = dados.nextDouble();
    dados.nextLine(); // <-------- aqui

    if (cui == 'i') {
        System.out.println("Taxa alfandega: ");
        double taxa = dados.nextDouble();
        dados.nextLine(); // <-------- aqui
        etc...
    } else if (cui == 'u') {
        System.out.print("Data de fabricação: dd/mm/yyyy: ");
        String formatoNormal = dados.nextLine();
        Date formato = sdf.parse(formatoNormal); // agora vai funcionar
etc...
```

Outra alternativa é ler a linha como string e depois converter para número (assim a quebra de linha é consumida e você não precisa chamar `nextLine` depois):

```
System.out.print("Entre com o numero de produto: ");
int numeroP = Integer.parseInt(dados.nextLine()); // <-------- aqui

for (int i = 1; i <= numeroP; i++) {
    System.out.println("Produto #" + i + " Data:");
    System.out.print("Comum, usado ou importado (c/u/i)? ");
    char cui = dados.nextLine().charAt(0);

    System.out.print("Nome: ");
    String nome = dados.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Preco: ");
    double preco = Double.parseDouble(dados.nextLine()); // <-------- aqui

    if (cui == 'i') {
        System.out.println("Taxa alfandega: ");
        double taxa = Double.parseDouble(dados.nextLine()); // <-------- aqui
        etc...
    } else if (cui == 'u') {
        System.out.print("Data de fabricação: dd/mm/yyyy: ");
        String formatoNormal = dados.nextLine();
        Date formato = sdf.parse(formatoNormal);
etc...
```