# Como fazer o Scanner do Java ler mais de uma vez em um programa utilizando classes?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, scanner

Tenho que fazer um código utilizando Programação Orientada a Objetos, onde você tem uma senha já pré-definida e utilizando o Scanner insere no mínimo três tentativas (uma de cada vez). O programa está lendo apenas uma tentativa, e utilizando o valor inserido para verificar todas as vezes do 'for', a dúvida é: como fazer para que o programa pergunte no mínimo 3 vezes qual a senha que eu quero inserir.

**main.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner_tentativa = new Scanner(System.in);
        String tentativa = scanner_tentativa.nextLine();
        Senha senha_banco;
        
        senha_banco = new Senha();
        senha_banco.entraSenha(tentativa);
    }
}
```

**Senha.java**

```
public class Senha {
    private String senha;
    private int count;
    private boolean block;
    
    public Senha(){
        this.senha = "123A";
        this.count = 0;
        this.block = false;
    }
    

    public void entraSenha(String tentativa) {
        for (this.count = 0; this.count <= 3; this.count++){
            if (tentativa == this.senha){
                System.out.println("Senha correta");
                this.count = 0;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Senha incorreta");
                this.count++;
            }
            if (this.count == 3){
                System.out.println("Senha incorreta");
                System.out.println("Senha bloqueada");
                this.block = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262976/101

Comment: Eu removi o Line de nextLine mas continua com o mesmo problema, quando eu insiro o primeiro valor ele já me da o "resultado final", que no caso seria o bloqueio da senha.

Answer (score 1):

Existe um problema sério na classe **Senha.java**. No método **entraSenha(String tentativa)** Você está comparando um objeto String *tentativa* com outro objeto String *senha*. Na linha:

```
if (tentativa == this.senha){
```

Sempre retornará falso porque esses objetos são diferentes (melhor explicando: as referências não apontam para o mesmo objeto). Mas se você quiser comparar as strings que esses dois objetos contêm, ou seja, o conteúdo das strings você pode usar um método que a classe String tem:

```
if (tentativa.equals(this.senha)){
```

Isso é um erro de lógica muito comum.