# Variavel tipo String não é lida no loop

Tags: java, string, while, netbeans, scanner

estou começando a aprender JAVA e tenho duvida com este código que escrevi, a variavel nome é lida a primeira vez no loop do while, mas na segunda vez em diante o netbeans 13 não espera o usuário digitar o nome e apresenta a segunda pergunta. alguém consegue me ajudar dizendo se tem algum erro neste código ?

```
/* 19. Escreva um algoritmo que leia o nome e o sexo de 56 pessoas e informe o 
 * nome e se ela é homem ou mulher. 
 * No final informe total de homens e de mulheres;
*/
package com.mycompany.exercicio19;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercicio19 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner leitorScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       String nome;
       char sexo;
       int cont = 5;
       int totalHomem = 0;
       int totalMulher = 0;
       
       while (cont > 0 ){
           System.out.println("Digite seu nome");
           nome = leitorScanner.nextLine();
           
           System.out.println(nome+" ,digite seu genero \n" +
                                   " M para mulher ou H para homem");
           sexo = leitorScanner.next().charAt(0);
           
           if  (sexo == 'h' || sexo == 'H'){
               totalHomem = totalHomem + 1;
               System.out.println(nome+" - sexo: Masculino");
           } else {
                    totalMulher = totalMulher + 1;
                    System.out.println(nome+" - sexo: Feminino");  
                     } 
           cont = cont - 1;
           System.out.println("");
       } 
       
        System.out.println("Total de Homens: "+totalHomem);
        System.out.println("Total de Mulheres: "+totalMulher);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Por que o Scanner retorna erro em algo que está dentro do esperado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262976/por-que-o-scanner-retorna-erro-em-algo-que-est%c3%a1-dentro-do-esperado)

Comment: Uma dica o Java salva strings de maneira diferente, então você não pode usar == para conferir strings salvas estaticamente, com strings salvas dinamicamente, você deve usar a função **equals()**

Comment: Não consigo comentar, pois não tenho 50 pontos de reputação. Peço desculpa por isso. Por favor, veja esse [tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/262981/100876), pois acredito que irá resolver o seu problema e sanar a sua dúvida.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode substituir o trecho `nome = leitorScanner.nextLine();` por `nome = leitorScanner.next();` que irá funcionar perfeitamente.

O método `nextLine()` avança o scanner além da linha atual, por isso apenas pedia o primeiro nome e depois ignorava todo o resto... Já o método `next()` da classe Scanner localiza o próximo token completo e o retorno é uma String, no caso a string que vc acabou de preencher durante o loop.